# How to replace text in the multiple svg files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to alter the text in the multiple svg files please help me out from this.

```
 for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
      filename = dirname+filename
      #print(filename)
      #for filename in pprint(dirlist):
         if filename.endswith(".svg"):
            with open(filename) as f:
            data = f.read()
            data = data.replace('NS', 'NSSS')
            f.close()
            f = open(/files/file.svg "wt")
            f.write(data)
            f.close()
```

Comment: a small example data and expected alteration will be helpful for us to help you, kr.

Comment: You can use `regex` `sub` function to replace text parts

Comment: please give more details (sample scenario), how do you alter text?

Comment: There are obvious syntax mistakes in your code, you should fix them first. For example missing quotes and comma in: `f = open(/files/file.svg "wt")`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
  if filename.endswith(".svg"):
    filename = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
      data = f.read()
    data = re.sub(r"NS", r"NSSS", data)
    with open('/files/file.svg', 'w') as f:
      f.write(data)
```

Comment: Hi @ismail durmaz how can we save the svg file with the opened file name.

Comment: @ShobhaHN you can change `open(filename, 'w')` instead of `open('/files/file.svg', 'w')`.